# Swift function won't let me return a Bool even though the functions has the return value

Tags: swift, xcode, return, boolean, func

I keep getting an error which says: *Unexpected non-void return value in void function*

The function clearly has a "-> Bool", but won't let me return a Bool value. 
The code i have commented out is alternative code which didn't work either.
I just want to return a Bool.

```
func checkUserSetup(userID: String) -> Bool {

    self.ref.child("userInfo").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var result: Bool

        if snapshot.hasChild(userID){
            print("DU HAR GÅTT GJENNOM SETUP!")
            result = true
            //return true
        }else{
            print("DU HAR IKKE GÅTT GJENNOM SETUP")
            result = false
            //return false
        }
        return result
    })
}//end of checkUserSetup
```

Comment: The function has a return value but the `observe...` closure – where the `return` statement belongs to – has none.

Answer (score 1):

You work with an asynchronous method. You cannot return your bool value in your block (async). I suggest you implement a completion handler in your method's param and turn your method to a void function.

```
 func checkUserSetup(userID: String, completion: @escaping ((success: Bool) -> Void))
```

And juste call

```
 completion(snapshot.hasChild(userID))
```

Comment: My bad. I'll edit that.